# Plugin Development: Read text from "Run" window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to read the text from the "Run" window or get the error text. 
As far I'v done, I'm able to read the text from the editor and NOT the "Run" window. Any idea on how this can be done ?

Comment: Check Grep Console plugin sources, it integrates in all different ways with the console. Or be more specific on the question.

Comment: Thank you @Meo ! will give it a try ! :)